# Uploading to Google Drive with Pythonanywhere

Tags: python, upload, google-drive-api, pythonanywhere

I'm a fairly new python user and I'm trying to upload a file to Google Drive using Pythonanywhere.  I have tried my script (below) on my PC successfully, but when I try it on Pythonanywhere I get an error.

Portion of script:

```
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

def sendtogoogle():
 drive = GoogleDrive()
 gpath = 'Myfolder'
 fname = 'Apicture.jpg'
 file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': "'root' in parents and trashed=false"}).GetList()
 for file1 in file_list:
     if file1['title'] == gpath:
         id = file1['id']
 file1 = drive.CreateFile({'title': fname, "parents":  [{"kind": "drive#fileLink","id": id}]})
 file1.SetContentFile(fname)
 file1.Upload()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
File "/home/myusername/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydrive/drive.py", line 2, in <module>
from .files import GoogleDriveFile
File "/home/myusername/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydrive/files.py", line 4, in <module> from apiclient import errors
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apiclient/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
from googleapiclient import channel
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googleapiclient/channel.py", line 63, in <module>
from googleapiclient import errors
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googleapiclient/errors.py", line 26, in <module>
from oauth2client import util
ImportError: cannot import name util
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Based from [issue #270](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/issues/270) in GitHub, error encountered seems like the oauth2client compatibility issue that was fixed in 1.5.2.

You may want to try removing this line in your code if you haven't done so:

```
from oauth2client import util
```

For more information, you may also visit [Google API Client Libraries > Python - Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/get_started).

Answer (score 0):

I had success using google-api-python-client on PythonAnywhere. I installed it with pip in a virtualenv.

My code was as follows.

```
    import httplib2
    import os
    from apiclient import discovery
    from googleapiclient.http import *
    from oauth2client import client
    from oauth2client import tools
    from oauth2client.file import Storage

    #This function was copied from the getting started guide on Google Drive API guide.
    credentials = get_credentials() 
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http)

    file_metadata = {'name' : how_you_want_name_of_file_to_appear_on_Google_Drive, 
                     'parents': [id_of_folder_in_Google_drive_to_upload_to]
                     }

     mime_string = 'application/pdf' #or whatever else you want
     media = MediaFileUpload(full_path_of_file_to_upload, mimetype = mime_string, resumable = False)

     file = service.files().create(body = file_metadata, media_body = media, fields = 'id').execute()
```

One caveat; I ran this on my local machine first and that's where I had the popup window about authorization. Then I just uploaded the credential file to my PythonAnywhere account. I never tried 'authorizing' from the PythonAnywhere server.